# WPF WebBrowser mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event onclick event fires inconsistently or not at all

Tags: wpf, events

Using VS 2019 .net framework 4.7 I have WPF form which contains a WebBrowser control.  I've configured the code below to receive html content mouse clicks.

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)WebBrowser.Document;
mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event iEvent;
iEvent = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)doc;
iEvent.onclick += IEvent_onclick;
```

The problem I'm having is, it only works sporadically.  I've seen other posts with the same issue but haven't found one with a solution.  Is there something I should be doing differently?

Thanks